# Why is the boxy version of the parser 13x faster than the fully specialized one?

Tags: f#

I am in the process of making the tutorials for the new [Spiral language](https://github.com/mrakgr/The-Spiral-Language) and have stumbled upon an interesting performance puzzle. What I am trying to do can be seen in [this chapter](https://github.com/mrakgr/The-Spiral-Language/tree/performance_conundrum#4-continuation-passing-style-monadic-computation-and-parsing) and the two generated programs are these: [boxy](https://github.com/mrakgr/The-Spiral-Language/blob/performance_conundrum/Testing/boxy.fsx) and [fully_specialized](https://github.com/mrakgr/The-Spiral-Language/blob/performance_conundrum/Testing/fully_specialized.fsx). What they are doing is just reading 3 ints from a string and returning them in a tuple. Surprisingly the boxy version is 13x (and up to 20x on some runs) faster than the fully specialized version. The timing are similar in scripted and compiled mode so it should be easy to test it in the Repl.

Before I try diving into the disassembly in order to try to figure it out, I have several ideas why this might be happening.

1) Improved cache locality due to a smaller code footprint. I do not think it is this one otherwise I would see the similar kind of improvement in a different example.

2) Black magic done by the JIT.

3) I am doing something wrong with benchmarking.

The program does seem to be working fine as far as I can tell, and nothing my eye can spot is amiss in the boxy version.

Any ideas of what is going on?

Comment: It is very unlikely that anybody would take the time to decipher your generated code. I suggest you reduce both examples to minimal reproducible form. As a bonus, while you're doing this, you might just discover the reason for the discrepancy.

Comment: I'll take your advice. I thought that something might come to mind if I posted this. Usually when it is something like this it turns out to be something stupid I've missed, but I do not get that feeling now so I was wondering if it could possibly have something to do with the F#'s optimizer that is making it go this much faster? The programs do in fact work.

Answer (score 1):

```
           Method |       Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
----------------- |-----------:|----------:|----------:|
       TermCasted |   406.6 ns | 1.2316 ns | 1.1520 ns |
             Boxy |   199.4 ns | 0.9976 ns | 0.9332 ns |
 FullySpecialized |   292.8 ns | 0.8448 ns | 0.7902 ns |
           FSharp | 3,616.2 ns | 8.9547 ns | 8.3762 ns |
```

When I use a proper [benchmarking tool](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) instead of an offhand script I get figures that make sense. The difference between boxy and fully specialized is 45%, not 1300% now. These figures are much more inline with what one would expect.

Spiral's parsers are also an order of magnitude faster than F#'s which is also what would be expected. Check out the tutorial's parsing chapter in [`master`](https://github.com/mrakgr/The-Spiral-Language) for more info.

The lesson from this is - never benchmark on you own, seriously. I intend to take this to heart from here.